Impact of Pixel Normalization Technique on Weights, Gradients, and Activations in Neural Network
There are different ways to process an image either before or during the training of a neural network trained to take in image inputs.
Some of the pixel adjustment techniques used:

Scaling each pixel as a fraction of the maximum pixel value
Centering each pixel to have a combined mean of 0
Normalizing each pixel so the distribution of the combined pixels have mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1

Additionally, the mean, max, and variance used in these operations can come from different samples:

A single channel within a single image
Across all channels in a single image
Across corresponding channels throughout the dataset
Across all channels throughout the entire dataset

Some of these techniques are used in popular deep learning models like VGG-16 and ResNet, and are even incorporated within layers like BatchNormalization and the choice of nonlinearities like relu to address problems such as vanishing gradients or exploding gradients.
How does each image normalization technique differ with respect to its impact on the development of weights, activations, and gradients in a shallow neural network or a deep learning model?
